# Insert attachments from custom uploader into post (regular uploader style)

Tags: uploads, attachments, tinymce, media, editor

I recently started using this nifty meta box framework:
http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box-script-for-wordpress/

I really like the plupload meta box, however, I need to be able to add the uploaded image into the editor rather than just attaching it to the post.

Any idea how I can create a button that inserts the correct attachment into the editor like it works with the regular "insert into post" button when uploading using the regular uploader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add content to the editor via javascript:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('<img src="hello.jpg">');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I googled around, all I could find is how to incorporate that code into a button in TinyMCE. How can I make a link within my metabox that sends images to the editor?

Comment: attach that javascript to the link in your metabox with an `onclick` or jQuery's `click` handler and pass whatever content you want inserted.